# How to see the synthesized RTL in openlane?

Tags: yosys

I have just started learning openlane. I want to see the RTL synthesis using openlane similar to how we get in vivado RTL synthesis. I have gone through the documentation but could not find anything regarding the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `write_verilog` Yosys command after every step. E.g., do `opt; fsm; opt` and after those passes you'll have a refined RTL.